# iOS null Interface Builder objects

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder, uilabel

G'day Folks

In this method...

```
- (void)configureTableWithTitle:(NSString *)theTitleText about:(NSString *)theAboutText
{
    debug(@"configuring with headerText: %@", theTitleText);
    debug(@"headerView description: %@", [headerView description]);
    debug(@"headerText description: %@", [headerText description]);
    CGPoint titleOrigin = headerText.frame.origin;
    CGSize titleSize = headerText.frame.size;
    [headerText setText:theTitleText];
    debug(@"headerText: %@", [headerText text]);
    CGSize newTitleSize = [theTitleText sizeWithFont:[headerText font] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(titleSize.width, 9999)];
    [headerText setFrame:CGRectMake(titleOrigin.x, titleOrigin.y, titleSize.width, newTitleSize.height)];
    int titleDelta = newTitleSize.height - titleSize.height;
    CGSize titleViewSize = headerView.frame.size;
    [headerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, titleViewSize.width, titleViewSize.height + titleDelta)];

    [[self tableView] setTableHeaderView:headerView];

    debug(@"footerView description: %@", [footerView description]);
    debug(@"footerText description: %@", [footerText description]);
    CGPoint aboutOrigin = footerText.frame.origin;
    CGSize aboutSize = footerText.frame.size;
    [footerText setText:theAboutText];
    CGSize newAboutSize = [theAboutText sizeWithFont:[footerText font] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(aboutSize.width, 9999)];
    [footerText setFrame:CGRectMake(aboutOrigin.x, aboutOrigin.y, aboutSize.width, newAboutSize.height)];
    int aboutDelta = newAboutSize.height - aboutSize.height;
    CGSize aboutViewSize = footerView.frame.size;
    [footerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, aboutViewSize.width, aboutViewSize.height + aboutDelta)];

    [[self tableView] setTableFooterView:footerView];
}
```

the lines that act on `footerView` & `footerText` work but those that act on `headerView` & `headerText` don't. This [screen shot](http://pedro.id.au/ib.png) shows how I have things hooked up in IB. The `debug` lines (Marcus Zarra's NSLog script) tell me that `headerView` & `headerText` are null from the beginning & that `headerText.text` is null after attempting to set the text. In the eader file I have...

```
@interface MFProgramDetailView : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate>
{
    UIView *headerView; 
    UIView *footerView; 
    UILabel *headerText;
    UILabel *footerText;
    UITableView *detailTable;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *headerView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *footerView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *headerText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *footerText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *detailTable;
```

I'm tearing my heair out over this one. I've checked & re-checked & fail to see anything out of place, I've compared it multiple times with another class using a similar method (but with items to juggle in the header) & can't see a difference.

Can anyone offer any clues as to how I'm getting this wrong? Given this is something I've done a few times p'aps familiarity has bred blindness.

Cheers & TIA,
Pedro

Comment: Are you checking your theTitleText parameter to see what that value is?

Comment: The first debug line does that & it is the expected text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In what method do you call your -(void)configureTableWithTitle: about: method?
Are you sure, that it's after viewDidLoad: ?

Comment: I had it called in the init method of each of 2 sub-classes. Moving it to viewDidLoad has fixed it. Thanks :)